# "between A and B" vs "between A or B"

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases, phrase-choice

The following is the headline of [an article from ClutchPoints](https://clutchpoints.com/matt-nagy-speaks-out-on-making-the-call-between-mitchell-trubisky-or-nick-foles/), sports news web site.

> Matt Nagy speaks out on making the call **between** Mitchell Trubisky **or**
> Nick Foles

While the phrase "between A and B" is very common, this is my first time to see the word "between" being used in combination with "or" as in "***between** Mitchell Trubisky **or** Nick Foles*".

Are "between A and B" and "between A or B" both interchangeable?

Answer (score 2):

These are not usually interchangeable. But here the headline is talking about *choosing* between the two, so "or" is possible.

Matt Nagy had to make a choice: keep Mitchell Trubisky on, or substitute Nick Foles. He made the call to bring on Foles.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. I now understand that they can be interchangeable when used in the meaning of choosing one from two options, but I'm very much curious at the same time about the other usages of the "between A or B" phrase, since  you described "**These are not usually interchangeable.**" Can you think of any good examples?